# Is there a way to use slideshare, but have it lock after one use?

Tags: php, javascript, slideshow

I am trying to run a system where a person can see slides but the content be locked after my presentation.

Is there a way using PHP / Javascript to make it lock after it has been viewed?
Further extending this could it be managed through a web CMS, i.e. turning its visibility on and off?

If not are there any alternatives to slideshare that allows me to do this?

Comment: Honestly I haven't tried anything yet. I would as Shawn Chin suggests use php / mysql to lock or unlock access however, I don't know whether [link](http://www.slideshare.net/) which would be my chosen distribution method, could link in to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using a database such as MySQL or MSSQL.
Create a table to hold references to your presentation slides.
Create another table to hold the username or IP address of the person who has seen your slides along side a foreign key to the slide he/she has seen and a flag as permission to indicate whether user can see slides again or not.
You can change this flag to make your slides visible or hidden.

Now, in PHP when a user wants to access your slides, you check whether you have registered the user in the table or not. If yes, then user has already seen your slides and it's up to you to show again or not. If not, then register the user in the table and show the slides.